# PagerTabStrip: change Tab Width

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs, android-viewpager

I am wondering about how to change the tab width in `Pager` Tab Strip

I have browse but it is like there are no one encountering the same problem as me..

My current layout is look like this:

[image: BigWidthTab]

But i am wondering how to create the tab that has small width like this with `PageTabStrip`

[image: SmallWidthTab]

Most of them are using external library like `ViewPagerIndicator`

Is it possible to do it with `PageTabStrip`? Thanks
Here is my current code

```
     <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

       <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
         android:id="@+id/pagerTabStrip"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="30dp"
         android:textColor= "@color/white"
         android:layout_gravity="top" >
       </android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip>

     </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Comment: Hi! Did you find a solution? I'm facing the same problem here :/
About the width and in my case I want to put the selected tab always on the left

Comment: @Caique hi there, sorry but i didnt find any solution.. The best solution i can offer is using external library.. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried setting the text spacing? That could be of help.
setTextSpacing api on the PagerTabStrip

Comment: Your question was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27577667/pagertabstrip-tabs-alignment-to-left

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PagerTabStrip tabs alignment to left](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27577667/pagertabstrip-tabs-alignment-to-left)

Comment: Thank you for noticing @chr1st3nd0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Question is answered here:
[PagerTabStrip tabs alignment to left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27577667/pagertabstrip-tabs-alignment-to-left)

> Use this before setViewPager():
>
> ```
> sliding_tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true);
> ```