# PagerTabStrip tabs alignment to left

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am using PagerTabStrip to set sliding tabs.  However, when I set three tabs, it shows the first tab in the center so users cannot see all three tabs at first glance.

How can I align them to left?

[image]

I want to move tabs to the left like this.

[image]

I tried gravity, but no luck.

```
pagerTabStrip.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
```

This is the code for MainActivity.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    PagerTabStrip pagerTabStrip = (PagerTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.pager_tab_strip);

    FragmentPagerAdapter fragmentPagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(fragmentPagerAdapter);

    pagerTabStrip.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
}
```

And

```
MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final String[] pageTitle = { "Entry", "History", "Report" };

    public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        Fragment fragment = new PageFragment();
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putString("pageIndex", Integer.toString(position + 1));
        fragment.setArguments(arguments);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return pageTitle.length;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return pageTitle[position];
    }

}
```

---

### **The Problem Solved!!**

You need to download the latest codes from github instead of google developer page.

[SlidingTabLayout.java](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/0a90bf8e6b90e9226f8c15b34eb7b1e4bf6d632e/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabLayout.java)

[SlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/0a90bf8e6b90e9226f8c15b34eb7b1e4bf6d632e/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabStrip.java)

Then, you can use setDistributeEvenly(true) like this.

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Get the ViewPager and set it's PagerAdapter so that it can display items
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    MyFragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(fragmentManager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Give the SlidingTabLayout the ViewPager, this must be done AFTER the ViewPager has had
    // it's PagerAdapter set.
    mSlidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    mSlidingTabLayout.setDistributeEvenly(true);
    mSlidingTabLayout.setViewPager(mViewPager);
}
```

Comment: sorry, I updated the question.

Comment: It turned out I can use SlidingTabLayout with some tweaks.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26803835/slidingtablayout-to-fit-the-screen

Comment: UPDATE:  The better way is to use sliding_tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); instead of the above solution.

Comment: Hey!! But I am using Pagertabstrip not sliding tablayout. How to achieve this in pagertabstrip??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use this before setViewPager():

```
sliding_tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true);
```

If you got this error `Cannot resolve method 'setDistributeEvenly(boolean)'`, you should update your SlidingTabLayout.java and SlidingTabStrip.java from Google I/O source code:

[SlidingTabLayout.java](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/0a90bf8e6b90e9226f8c15b34eb7b1e4bf6d632e/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabLayout.java)

[SlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/0a90bf8e6b90e9226f8c15b34eb7b1e4bf6d632e/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabStrip.java)

Comment: i tried this but no effect on my code so is there anyother changes to be done?

Comment: @Anitha call it before setViewPager()

Comment: Let me ask. The idea is to replace android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip with SlidingTabLayout right?

Comment: Could I see your layout xml file? :(