# PagerTabStrip Show tabs in single page

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am using `PageViewer` and `PagerTabStrip` for swiping through the screen with tabs in Xamarin.Android. But It shows one tab per page. I want to show all 5 tabs on a single page.

This is already explained for Android [PagerTabStrip tabs alignment to left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27577667/pagertabstrip-tabs-alignment-to-left), but I want this in Xamarin.Android.

[image: Phone]

Comment: Did you try the property `DistributeEvenly` on the `PagerTabStrip`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `SlidingTabLayout` class and `SlidingTabStrip` class. The link you posted, they are java codes, you just need change them to c# codes and then you will solve your problem. [here is a vedio baout `SlidingTabLayout`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Rr0ZCvX_Zs), and [here is a demo which contains the classes](http://cforbeginners.com/SlidingTabLayoutTutorial.zip), just copy it to your project and reference in you layout.

Comment: Lv MSFT  i want to add button in page ,and if i click on that button it should to to particulat pagerView .can you help