# Tabs on a single page

Tags: android, xml, android-viewpager, android-tabs

I'm currently using a `ViewPager` with a `PagerTabStrip` to display 4 tabs at the top of the device. All I want to do is have 4 tabs fixed in place and centered, but I can't figure out how to do that now that the old way (using Action bar tabs) has been deprecated.

Basically I have something like this:
[image]

But I want it so that all 4 of my tabs are on the same page (all visible).

This is my code to set the pager adapter to the `ViewPager`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(new MainPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

}
```

and this is the relevant XML:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_tab_strip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="@color/theme_color"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:paddingTop="18dp"
        android:paddingBottom="18dp"/>

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

So how would I fix the tabs using `PagerTabStrip`? If I can't, what else can I use to do it?

Note: similar questions have been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049339/pagertabstrip-change-tab-width?rq=1) but I can't find any solid answers that work. Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25493840/how-to-visible-all-the-time-3-tab-on-pagertabstrip?rq=1) as well.

Comment: Are you trying to create the material design tabs like this? https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/7454787/7192840/853c99a4-e467-11e4-8259-aa45df5dfddd.PNG

Comment: Yeah, exactly. But the way I know how to do it is deprecated with Android L so I'm pretty lost

Comment: I will post code for you using another library I just need to know if you are using fragment as the tabs.

Comment: Thanks -- yeah, using fragments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need any more information post it in the comment below.

First you want to add the library to the project in the gradle or install the library.

**Gradle** add compile 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.0.9' or download project at https://github.com/jpardogo/PagerSlidingTabStrip

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.eugene.pagertesting"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.0.9'
}
```

**XML**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:minHeight="56dp"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"/>


    <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:textColorPrimary="@color/white"
        app:pstsDividerColor="@color/primary"
        app:pstsIndicatorColor="@color/white"
        app:pstsIndicatorHeight="2dp"
        app:pstsShouldExpand="true"
        app:pstsUnderlineHeight="0dp"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**PagerAdapter**

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    private Fragment f = null;

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) { // Returns Fragment based on position
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                f = new FragmentPageOne();
                break;
            case 1:
                f = new FragmentPageTwo();
                break;
        }
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() { // Return the number of pages
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) { // Set the tab text
        if (position == 0) {
            return "Fragment One";
        }
        if (position == 1) {
            return "Fragment Two";
        }
        return getPageTitle(position);
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ViewPager viewPager;
    PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;
    PagerSlidingTabStrip pagerSlidingTabStrip;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        pagerSlidingTabStrip = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        pagerSlidingTabStrip.setViewPager(viewPager);
    }
}
```

[image]

If you want to know how I styled the app I will post that as well just let me know.

**UPDATE**
if you would like to drop the shadow below the tabs I can post that as well.

Comment: @uj- no problem.  Code on!

Comment: Quick question: would you happen to know if it would be possible to nest another `PagerSlidingTabStrip` inside a particular tab, without attaching a `ViewPager` to it? I want to put a couple tabs under the first tab of the `PagerSlidingTabStrip` but I don't want to be able to swipe between them because that will interfere with the first set of tab's `ViewPager`. It's cool if you're not sure how to this though.

Comment: You can add a another viewpager within a viewpager.  Just set the height of that viewpager to be small so you can swipe between the main pages.

Comment: If I set the height of the `ViewPager` to be small won't that hide the fragments that it pages through?

Comment: @EugeneH how to set only 1 tab visible at a time.. In your image you have fragment 1 and 2. I want fragment 1 to cover the entire screen.. I've followed this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/)

Comment: @Prabs So you are not looking for Tabs?

Comment: @EugeneH Yes, I am looking for tabs.. but in your pic you have 2 tabs visible on screen..like tab 1 and tab 2..if you swipe forward then you get tab 2 and tab 3 on screen.. Similarly I want only tab 1 visible on screen.When you swipe tab 2 should come then tab 3..but each tab should occupy the 100% of screen. In your case every tab is occupying 50% of the screen

Comment: @Prabs that is against google design guidelines. I suggest not using tabs at all.  Just use the Toolbar and viewpager.  When the user swipes to the other screens, just change the toolbar title.

Comment: @EugeneH Do You want me to remove the tabs and listen to the swipe actions(may be by using `OnSwipeTouchListener()` ) and perform any set of methods like changing the title, changing the content etc. Is that what you are saying??